# Different result on SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

When executed on SQL Server 2008, the result comes as expected in random order. But when executed on SQL Server 2012, the result comes in the same order which is present in the main table which is asc.

Can't figure out where I am lacking. Here's the query which I am running in SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2012.

```
insert into CategoryImage1(ImageId, categoryid, thumbnail,
ImageName, GridviewImage, CreatedOn, ModifiedOn, Coordinates, ActiveFlag)
   select 
      imageid, categoryid, thumbnail, ImageName, 
      GridviewImage, CreatedOn, ModifiedOn, Coordinates, ActiveFlag 
   from 
      CategoryImage 
   order by 
      newid()
```

Comment: Why would you want to insert into a table in a random order? surely any randomness should be done when querying? Also, are the indexes (especially clustered ones) the same on both servers?

Comment: So, the problem is that the optimizer was smart enough to realize that `order by newid()` had no meaning for this insert (since tables are inherently unordered bags of rows) and so avoided it?

Comment: [Even simple changes can cause trouble][1] : talks about ordering issues when adding TempDb files. May not be completely related to your issue


  [1]: http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2011/08/tempdb-multiplefiles-sort/

Comment: @RowlandShaw I want to have a shuffled record from my table without repetition. For this I thought this process to put all the data into another table randomly

Comment: A table in SQL Server (or any other, serious RDBMS) has **no inherent order** (or "natural" or "system" order or whatever you might call it). You **only** get an order when you do a `SELECT` with an **explicit** `ORDER BY`

Comment: please try my answer. It was downvoted for unrelated reasons, but I still think it is the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your `SELECT` statement is executed to return the rows. The query optimizer determines the most efficient way to return those rows based upon available indexes, column statistics, etc. They may therefore be in table order, or another order. The order is nondeterministic, and may depend on many factors, including available memory, disk IO etc. etc.

The results are then ordered by newid(). This is a scalar function so is executed against each row in the order they have already been returned. Somebody please correct me if I am incorrect here, but the net effect of this will be zero (other than some wasted CPU cycles).

These results are then inserted into your target table.

So, to summarise, the reason SQL Server 2012 is inserting them in a different order is that it is choosing a different execution planto SQL Server 2008. This may be due to changes in the way the optimizer weights plans in 2012, or a difference in the shape of the data, 'freshness' or column / index statistics, available resources, server architecture, etc. etc.

If you want to insert your columns in a deterministic order, make sure your order by clause orders by one or more unique columns in the source data.

Comment: it will not change a thing to refer to a unique column in the *ORDER BY* clause

Comment: @t-clausen.dk - if you specify a column with unique values in the `ORDER BY` clause (e.g. `ORDER BY ImageId`), then the data will be returned in this order, and then inserted into the target table in the same order. This is what I meant by 'unique column', rather than something with duplicate values. In other words, you have to order the data by something deterministic, or by definition, you don't know what order you will get the data in.

Comment: Note that there is a **BIG** difference between non-deterministic and random. If you want your rows back in a random order, then you need to introduce a source of randomness, SQL Server **cannot** do this for you. To do this, you would require at the very least a UDF to return a pseudo-random number. A full discussion of randomness, and why computers can't provide true randomness (by definition) is well beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

Per [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942.aspx) `newid()` is of type `uniqueidentifier` and order is not guaranteed. Quote from documentation

> Comparison operators can be used with uniqueidentifier values.
>   However, ordering is not implemented by comparing the bit patterns of
>   the two values.

So in your case, `order by newid()` essentially has no effect at all and bound to generate inconsistent order. Rather try ordering by a specific column like `order by imageid`.

Comment: OP is expecting output in random order which is happening in SQL Server 2008 but not in 2012

Comment: @t-clausen.dk, updated the post. Link should work now.

Comment: @AnujTripathi, there is nothing called random order. Either you order by a column or leave it, in which case there is no order guranteed.

Comment: @Rahul is there any way to put shuffled records from one table to another.

Comment: @Rahul by using order by imageid I'll get the result either in Asc or Desc order. But I want the record in random order or say shuffled

Comment: @MohitRakhra, if that's what you want then remove `order by` alltogether. In which case the resultant data will not follow in inherent order.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a set of rows in a new, random, order, then you need to *store* the random values so that you can use them in an `ORDER BY` when you *query* the data. **Only** that `ORDER BY` determines the order of results<sup>1</sup>.

So:

```
create table CategoryImage1 (
   ... --Columns as before
   ,NewRandomColumn uniqueidentifier not null
)

insert into CategoryImage1(ImageId,categoryid,thumbnail,
ImageName,GridviewImage,CreatedOn,ModifiedOn,Coordinates,ActiveFlag,

NewRandomColumn)

select imageid,categoryid,thumbnail,
ImageName,GridviewImage,CreatedOn,ModifiedOn,Coordinates,ActiveFlag,

newid()

from CategoryImage
```

And then later:

```
select imageid,categoryid,thumbnail,
ImageName,GridviewImage,CreatedOn,ModifiedOn,Coordinates,ActiveFlag
from CategoryImage1 order by NewRandomColumn
```

---

<sup>1</sup>[`ORDER BY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms188385.aspx):

> The order in which rows are returned in a result set are **not guaranteed** unless an ORDER BY clause is specified.

(**My emphasis**)

Comment: This is a real nice idea, must admit.

Comment: Tried this solution. but the result is same on SQL Server 2012 as it was earlier

Comment: @MohitRakhra - have you taken onboard what everyone has been saying - that the order the rows are stored in the table is undefined and so it's critical to have an `ORDER BY` on any select that *queries* this set of rows in order to get the random ordering?

Comment: this has references to an imaginary table. More importantly It will mix the rows from each insert (when there are more than 1 insert), so every insert will be mixed by earlier inserts which is clearly not the meaning in the question.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk - it had a typo on the table name which is fixed. Your "more importantly" concerns are ones that are present in the OPs current code.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Still the same result. is there any other method which I can work upon to have the shuffled records.

Comment: @MohitRakhra - the solution I've presented should work - where we store a "shuffle" parameter and then use that in an `ORDER BY` when *querying* the data. I can't help but feel that you're still (despite lots of people here telling you otherwise) convinced that there's some inherent order in which the rows are *stored* in the table, that you can obtain and rely upon.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Your query is working on the Select statement. What I want to achieve is to work on the shuffled record on insertion. After executing your insert query, record is still getting saved in the same order as it is saved in the CategoryImage table.

Comment: @MohitRakhra - and this is what multiple people are trying to tell you. There is **no** inherent order to a table that you can rely upon. The **only** guarantee you can obtain is to use an `ORDER BY` clause when you **query** those rows. Your code **assumed** that there was some "order" in tables that you can rely on. That was a bad assumption. Trying to get an answer that restores that assumption isn't going to work.